# angularjs and spring app not running from war file

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I have been developing an app that uses angularjs and spring mvc.  The app runs perfectly in eclipse when I do `Run As...Run on Server` and view in my web browser at `localhost : 8080 / appname`.

But now I have used the eclipse maven pugin to build a war file and deploy the war to a remote server.  When I type in the domain name on the remote server, I just get the text from the main index page, without any of the javascript, or css.  Since the links are all javascript, and the index page relies on client-side includes, all I can access in the browser from the remote server is a small amount of unformatted text with no links.

**Is there an extra step to creating an executable war with angularjs that I am not aware of?**  The methods I used to create the war and install it on the server have worked many times with spring-only apps running on the same server, and developed in the same eclipse installation on the same devbox.

**How can I start to diagnose this problem?  I am new to angularjs.**

Comment: Did you make sure that the file is set to run an an executable and that all your file paths are correct?

Comment: @EvanBechtol I am new to angularjs.  This is my first angular app.  The paths may be relative to `appname` in `localhost : 8080 / appname`.  So maybe I need to set the javascript to recognize a more flexible application context.  But I just assumed that eclipse and tomcat could handle that the say way they handle it in java.  Also, this is a war file, so I assumed that meant it was executable by definition.  What specific steps can I take to do what you suggest?

Comment: the file IS executable by default, but it never hurts to check the execution permissions as a quick first step. I think that the problem would lie in the javascript if the program works in Eclipse already. Javascript is much more picky than Java is and less informative on the error messages. Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

how do you render angular files? Do you use JSP + Angular?

If you are using just static files to serve angular html then your static file serving is working.This means that something wrong is going with your javascript and css files mapping (wrong urls)
otherwise if you render jsp + angular then maybe your static content serving is not working properly

Does your browser say that mappings are wrong?(check it out in browsers console)
How did you map paths to your css and javascript?